# abntex2 package chapter creation not working

Tags: errors, abnt

I am trying to compile this simple document using `abntex2` class but for some strange reason I am receiving the following two errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.175 \chapter{Capítulo 1}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.175 \chapter{Capítulo 1}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

The code is simply this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Adriano, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)`

Comment: Tanks, i am still trying to figure out the formatting on the forum, tnks for the fix =)

Comment: This teaches me 2 tings, that latex is really weird, and that i should always post here the question before wasting 20h of my life trying to figure it out by my own... lol Tanks very much!

Comment: In the update from version 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 of `abntex2.cls` the line `\RequirePackage{calc}` has been removed, but the standard chapter style for the class requires it. Please, make the maintainers of the class aware of the problem.

Comment: @egreg: I browsed their GitHub repository and found the issue has already been reported: https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/issues/140

Comment: The `abntex2` bundle has been updated and is now in TeX Live; the new version has fixed the issue and will be available in TeX Live 2015.

Comment: Good! that was quick!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** (Guilherme Z. Santos): this issue has been [reported and fixed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239986/abntex2-package-chapter-creation-not-working/240000#comment572131_239986) at the TeX Live 2015 distribution, if you are still experiencing this problem besides the below solution another attempt is to update you TeX distribution.

---

The class seems to assume, but not load, the `calc` package.

this works

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}


\chapter{test}
a
\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Witchcraft, witchcraft, witchcraft! I wub you. ♥ `:)`